# How to parse a OFX (Version 1.0.2) file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, sgml, ofx

I have a [OFX](http://www.ofx.net/) file downloaded from [Citibank](https://www.citibank.com.co/), this file has a DTD defined at http://www.ofx.net/DownloadPage/Files/ofx102spec.zip (file OFXBANK.DTD), the OFX file appear to be [SGML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SGML/) valid.
I'm trying with [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) of PHP 5.4.13, but I get several warning and file is not parsed. My Code is:

```
$file = "source/ACCT_013.OFX";
$dtd = "source/ofx102spec/OFXBANK.DTD";
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$doc->schemaValidate($dtd);
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
```

The OFX file start as:

```
OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:102
SECURITY:NONE
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:NONE

<OFX>
<SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
<SONRS>
<STATUS>
<CODE>0
<SEVERITY>INFO
</STATUS>
<DTSERVER>20130331073401
<LANGUAGE>SPA
</SONRS>
</SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
<BANKMSGSRSV1>
<STMTTRNRS>
<TRNUID>0
<STATUS>
<CODE>0
<SEVERITY>INFO
</STATUS>
<STMTRS>
<CURDEF>COP
<BANKACCTFROM> ...
```

I'm open to install and use any program in Server (Centos) for call from PHP.

PD: This class http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5778-PHP-Parse-and-extract-financial-records-from-OFX-files.html don't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first of all even XML is a subset of SGML a valid SGML file must not be a well-formed XML file. XML is more strict and does not use all features that SGML offers.

As `DOMDocument` is XML (and not SGML) based, this is not really compatible.

Next to that problem, please see *2.2 Open Financial Exchange Headers* in Ofexfin1.doc it explains you that

> The contents of an Open Financial Exchange file consist of a simple set of headers followed by contents defined by that header

and further on:

> A blank line follows the last header. Then (for type OFXSGML), the SGML-readable data begins with the <OFX> tag.

So locate the first blank line and strip everyhing until there. Then load the SGML part into DOMDocument by converting the SGML into XML first:

```
$source = fopen('file.ofx', 'r');
if (!$source) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to open OFX file.');
}

// skip headers of OFX file
$headers = array();
$charsets = array(
    1252 => 'WINDOWS-1251',
);
while(!feof($source)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($source));
    if ($line === '') {
        break;
    }
    list($header, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $headers[$header] = $value;
}

$buffer = '';

// dead-cheap SGML to XML conversion
// see as well http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PostprocessingAutoClosedSGMLTagsWithTheSGMLReader.aspx
while(!feof($source)) {

    $line = trim(fgets($source));
    if ($line === '') continue;

    $line = iconv($charsets[$headers['CHARSET']], 'UTF-8', $line);
    if (substr($line, -1, 1) !== '>') {
        list($tag) = explode('>', $line, 2);
        $line .= '</' . substr($tag, 1) . '>';
    }
    $buffer .= $line ."\n";
}

// use DOMDocument with non-standard recover mode
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$save = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
libxml_use_internal_errors($save);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This code-example then outputs the following (re-formatted) XML which also shows that DOMDocument loaded the data properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OFX>
  <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
    <SONRS>
      <STATUS>
        <CODE>0</CODE>
        <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
      </STATUS>
      <DTSERVER>20130331073401</DTSERVER>
      <LANGUAGE>SPA</LANGUAGE>
    </SONRS>
  </SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
  <BANKMSGSRSV1>
    <STMTTRNRS>
      <TRNUID>0</TRNUID>
      <STATUS>
        <CODE>0</CODE>
        <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
      </STATUS>
      <STMTRS><CURDEF>COP</CURDEF><BANKACCTFROM> ...</BANKACCTFROM>
</STMTRS>
    </STMTTRNRS>
  </BANKMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

I do not know whether or not this can be validated against the DTD then. Maybe this works. Additionally if the SGML is not written with the values that are of a tag on the same line (and only a single element on each line is required), then this fragile conversion will break.

Comment: Thank you, it work. It was converted to php array with http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

Comment: the format looks somewhat flat. you might want to use this variant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15729905/367456 - it's a single line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest OFX parse into an array with easy access to all values and transactions.

```
function parseOFX($ofx) {
    $OFXArray=explode("<",$ofx);
    $a=array();
    foreach ($OFXArray as $v) {
        $pair=explode(">",$v);
        if (isset($pair[1])) {
            if ($pair[1]!=NULL) {
                if (isset($a[$pair[0]])) {
                    if (is_array($a[$pair[0]])) {
                        $a[$pair[0]][]=$pair[1];
                    } else {
                        $temp=$a[$pair[0]];
                        $a[$pair[0]]=array();
                        $a[$pair[0]][]=$temp;
                        $a[$pair[0]][]=$pair[1];
                    }
                } else {
                    $a[$pair[0]]=$pair[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this:

```
$source = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('a.ofx'));

//add end tag
$source = preg_replace('#^<([^>]+)>([^\r\n]+)\r?\n#mU', "<$1>$2</$1>\n", $source);

//skip header
$source = substr($source, strpos($source,'<OFX>'));

//convert to array
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);

print_r($array);
```