# how-to-parse-a-ofx-version-1-0-2-file-in power BI?

Tags: ofx

I just read
[How to parse a OFX (Version 1.0.2) file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735330/how-to-parse-a-ofx-version-1-0-2-file-in-php?newreg=73c1f3f8e1c34cbabd4965fd01f011d2)

I am not a developer. What easy tool can I use  to make this code run with no code skill or appetence ? web browser is pretty hard to use for non dev guys.

I need this to use the file into Power BI, which accept M code, json source or xml, but not sgml ofx or PHP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Didier to StackOverflow!

I'm going to try and give you a clue how I'd approach the problem here. But keep in mind that your question really lacks details for us to help you, and I'm asking to update your question with example data that you want to integrate into PowerBI. Also, I'm not too familiar with PowerBI nor PHP, and won't go into making that PHP code you linked run for you.

Rather, I'd suggest to convert your OFX file into XML, and then use PowerBI's XML import on that converted file.

From your linked question, I get that your OFX file is in SGML format. There's a program specifically designed to convert SGML into XML (which is just a restricted form of SGML) called `osx`. I've detailed how to install it on Linux and Mac OS in [another question related to SGML-to-XML down-converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450793/adding-missing-xml-closing-tags-in-javascript/50457717#50457717); if you're on Windows, you may have luck by just downloading a really ancient (32bit) version of it from ftp://ftp.jclark.com/pub/sp/win32/sp1_3_4.zip. Alternatively, you can use my sgmljs.net software as explained in [Converting HTML to XML](http://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html#converting-html-to-xml)  though that tutorial is really about the much more complex task of converting HTML to XML/XHTML and will probably confuse you.

Anyway, if you manage to install `osx`, running it on your OFX file (which I assume to have the name `yourfile.ofx` just for illustration) is just a matter of invoking (on the Windows or Linux/Mac OS command line):

```
osx yourfile.ofx > yourfile.xml
```

to result in `yourfile.xml` which you can attempt to load with PowerBI.

Chances are your OFX file has additional text at the beginning (lines like `XYZ:0001` that come before `<ofx>`). In that case, you can just remove those lines using a text editor before invoking `osx` on it. Maybe you also need a `.dtd` file or additional instructions at the top of the OFX file informing SGML about the grammar of your file; it's really difficult to say without seeing actual test data.

Before bothering with SGML and all that, however, I suggest to remove those first few lines in your OFX file (everything until the first `<` character) and check if PowerBI can already recognize your changed input file as XML (which, from other OFX example files, has a good chance of succeeding). Be sure to work on a copy of your original file rather than overwriting it. Then come back and update your question with your results and example data.